# Monaco: comment keyboard-shortcut for custom language

Tags: monaco-editor, monarch

I am using monaco (`"monaco-editor": "^0.38.0"`) with a custom language profile and I want `cmd+/` to toggle line commenting.

My main js file has

```
import { monaco } from "./customMonaco";
```

customMonaco has

```
import "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.all.js";
import "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/comment/browser/comment.js";
...
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js";
import "./mix.contribution.js";
export { monaco };
```

mix.contribution reads

```
import {language} from "./mix.js"

monaco.languages.register({
    id: "mix",
    extensions: [".mix"],
    aliases: ["Mix", "mix"],
});

monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('mix', language);
```

and mix.js includes

```
export const language = {
  ...
  comment: [[/[^\/\/*]+/, "comment"]],
  ...
}
```

some key bindings work (e.g. cmd+z) but not the one I want. What might I be missing?

I tried adding this after the code instantiating monaco

```
        const blockContext = "editorTextFocus";
        this.editor.addAction({
            id: "toggleComment",
            label: "Toggle Comment",
            keybindings: [KeyMod.CtrlCmd | KeyCode.Slash],
            // contextMenuGroupId: "2_execution",
            precondition: blockContext,
            run: () => {
                console.log("comment toggle");
            },
        });
```

This does log to the console but I can't find a command to toggle comments that i could add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to tokenisation, you also need to set the [comment rules](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/languages.CommentRule.html) of your language in the [language configuration](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/languages.LanguageConfiguration.html#comments):

```js
const languageConfiguration: monaco.languages.LanguageConfiguration = {
    comments: {
      lineComment: "//",
      blockComment: [ "/*", "*/" ]
    },
    ... //The rest of your language configuration
}
```

And then apply the configuration:

```js
monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration('mix', languageConfiguration)
```

Comment: thanks I had only been using `monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider` so far